# Don't want email about new post in a subscribed tag when I'm the one that posted it in the first place

Tags: feature-request, email, subscriptions

I'm "subscribed" to the [ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruamel.yaml) tag, so that I get notified when a new question is posted. That works fine. I am even under the impression that if I visited a question, that would trigger an email (e.g. after searching for new questions on the site itself), that the system is smart enough to notice and not send an email.

Today I posted a question with an answer, tagged [ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruamel.yaml), about something that was originally posted as a feature request for [ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruamel.yaml) and which already can be done. I posted the answer along with the question.

And within a few minutes, I got a notification via email that there was a new `ruamel.yaml` related item in my Stack Exchange feed. That item did have a very familiar title...

Can we please get rid of such subscription notifications for self-posted questions?

Comment: "that the system is smart enough to notice and not sent an email." I'm pretty sure I received emails for questions after I seen them on the site.

Comment: Aw, don't you want to see your name up in lights? `;-)`

Comment: _All or Nothing_ your choice

Comment: "that the system is smart enough to notice and not sent an email." I wouldn't expect this. This is a complex feature. SO can't do much regarding email delays after they send it. They would also have to control when the email is sent compared to when the website updates. In theory, the control can be done on user's periodical request; but, it's extra complexity when the problem can still appear after they send out the email. Of course, the feature that you are asking for wouldn't suffer since the system knows who to email and who is posting the question.